# jQuery Modify Anchor Text after inserting it into a div

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic-code

I have the following problem.

I need to modify the anchor text after is added dinamically inside a div.

In my code:

The "Load file" button add the file loaded link in the div class = "div" (it's a simulation).
The program that loads the file can't be modified.

That program returns the Anchor text with path and file name, but I just want to keep the name.

The problem is that I don't find in which event put my code to modify the anchor text. 
I did a test and it works with the mousemove event, but is just a test.

How to trigger the code that modify the anchor text?

The code below not works, but you can try enabling the mousemove event to see the desired result.

Thanks in advance! for your help...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
          // alert("Alert  Click");
     $('.div').append(
            '<a id="link-x" href="http://example.com/file-3.pdf">http://example.com/file-3.pdf</a><br>');
 });
  
/*    This Works only for Testing
    $(document).mousemove(function () {
        $('a[id*="link"]').each(function(){
            var text = $( this ).text();
            var html = $( this ).html();
            var res = text .replace( 'http://example.com/', '' );
            $( this ).text( res );
        });
 });
*/    
    $('a[id*="link"]').on(function () {
        $('a[id*="link"]').each(function(){
            var text = $( this ).text();
            var html = $( this ).html();
            var res = text .replace( 'http://example.com/', '' );
            $( this ).text( res );
        });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycode">
<button id="btnSave">Load File</button>
</div>
<div class="div">
<a id="link-x" href="http://example.com/file-1.pdf">file-1.pdf</a><br>
<a id="link-x" href="http://example.com/file-2.pdf">file-2.pdf</a><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        $('[id*="link"]').text(function() {
            return $(this).text().replace("http://example.com/", "");
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tu9Ln69/1/).

Comment: Hi Gothdo,
 Thanks for your response,
The code on the button is a simulation, that code can't be modified.
In the reallity I don'have access to that code.
What I get is links that need to change for anyone to see the file path.

Comment: @Memo So in reality, do the link appear after clicking `#btnSave`?

Comment: Yes The links appear after clicking #btnSave, then how change that anchor text? which is the event that can be catched? after the dynamic code appear.

Comment: @Memo You can just add another click event listener in your code, see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tu9Ln69/1/);

Comment: in this example that you do works fine, but in my app not works, I need something else that does not depend, clicking on the button Thanks!

Comment: In my app, when you click the button is displayed a screen to choose a file to load from your pc, after you choose a file and click upload is when the links appear, is because can't listen the button, cause when you do click on button "Load file" the links not exist on the screen yet.